# Restore-SPSite : Could not find file error in sp2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Getting Restore-SPSite : Could not find file  error while trying to restore sp 2013 site from production to testing env.

I took backup from production using CA and copied the Bakup folder to testing env and then tried to restore and given the same path but getting errors.

For more info..

```
PS C:\Users\aul> Restore-SPSite -Identity http://10.0.7.11:333/sites/setesting -path F:\ProductionEnv\00000000.bak-Force
```

> Confirm
>   Are you sure you want to perform this action?
>   Performing the operation "Restore-SPSite" on target
>   "http://10.0.7.11:333/sites/setesting".
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
>   (default is "Y"):y
>   Restore-SPSite : Could not find file 'F:\ProductionEnv\00000000.bak-Force'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Restore-SPSite -Identity http://10.0.7.11:333/sites/seutesting -path
>   F:\Producti ...
>
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
>     SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], FileNotFoundException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
>       ite

Please if anyone knows the solution for this then kindly tell me,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you perform backup of production site again with using full path

```
Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak -UseSqlSnapshot
```

In the path give full address including file name .bak, it will generate a single file then move that to test farm and run restore with same full path.

Comment: I willl try and update you sir,

But I need to take backup of web application because in that web application we have 2 site collections,

Web Application url is https://sharepoint.see.net/ 
May I know what command do I have to use ??
And is it neccessary to take backup in C:?

Comment: You can run backup command against each site collection one by one. URL will be change and file name in each command... it is recommended that don't use system drive means c drive, use other

Comment: Okay sir, Thank you.

May I please know can I take backup using CA?

Comment: Sir I tried to take backup from production using powershell, when I'm adding .bak file it's showing an error
I'm using following command, but getting error.
'Backup-SPFarm -Directory 'E:\SeuPortal_Bak\seu.bak' -BackupMethod full -Item 'SEU Portal - 443' -Verbose'

If I just give any folder name like E:SeuPortal_Bak its starting backup process.

May I please know what should I do??

Comment: you are trying to get the farm backup while you need only site collection backup...to get the site collection backup...run this one Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path E:\SeuPortal_Bak\seu.bak